# Compilation error on insert-or-update action in Quill when using H2 database

Tags: scala, compiler-errors, h2, insert-update, quill

is it possible to perform insert-or-update action in Quill when using H2 database? If I add to `.insert` action `.onConflictIgnore`, I'm getting compilation error:

```scala
[error] [...]/repository/HeadlinesRepository.scala:41:36: exception during macro expansion: 
[error] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Action ast can't be translated to sql: 'querySchema("headlines").insert(v => v.link -> ?, v => v.title -> ?).onConflictIgnore'
[error]         at io.getquill.util.Messages$.fail(Messages.scala:15)
[error]         at io.getquill.context.sql.idiom.SqlIdiom.$anonfun$actionTokenizer$1(SqlIdiom.scala:387)
[error]         at io.getquill.idiom.StatementInterpolator$Tokenizer$$anon$1.token(StatementInterpolator.scala:17)
[error]         at io.getquill.idiom.StatementInterpolator$TokenImplicit.token(StatementInterpolator.scala:27)
[error]         at io.getquill.context.sql.idiom.SqlIdiom.$anonfun$astTokenizer$1(SqlIdiom.scala:57)
[error]         at io.getquill.idiom.StatementInterpolator$Tokenizer$$anon$1.token(StatementInterpolator.scala:17)
[error]         at io.getquill.context.sql.idiom.SqlIdiom$$anon$1.token(SqlIdiom.scala:49)
[error]         at io.getquill.context.sql.idiom.SqlIdiom$$anon$1.token(SqlIdiom.scala:46)
[error]         at io.getquill.idiom.StatementInterpolator$TokenImplicit.token(StatementInterpolator.scala:27)
[error]         at io.getquill.context.sql.idiom.SqlIdiom.translate(SqlIdiom.scala:39)
[error]         at io.getquill.context.sql.idiom.SqlIdiom.translate$(SqlIdiom.scala:23)
[error]         at io.getquill.H2Dialect$.translate(H2Dialect.scala:20)
[error]         at io.getquill.context.ContextMacro.translateStatic(ContextMacro.scala:51)
[error]         at io.getquill.context.ContextMacro.translate(ContextMacro.scala:37)
[error]         at io.getquill.context.ContextMacro.expand(ContextMacro.scala:24)
[error]         at io.getquill.context.ContextMacro.expand$(ContextMacro.scala:21)
[error]         at io.getquill.context.ActionMacro.expand(ActionMacro.scala:10)
[error]         at io.getquill.context.ActionMacro.expandBatchAction(ActionMacro.scala:121)
[error]         at io.getquill.context.ActionMacro.runBatchAction(ActionMacro.scala:71)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that no.

> insert or update (upsert, conflict)
>
> Upsert is supported by Postgres, SQLite, and MySQL

https://github.com/getquill/quill

Comment: I was afraid that it's not supported for H2, I hoped I'm wrong. :) Thank you for the answer.